# Bazel run with tags

Tags: python, bazel

This is more of a general question regarding the capabilities of Bazel. Does Bazel have the capability of running multiple tests at once based on a tag?

Similar to how 
`bazel build --build_tag_filter=example_test //path/...`
builds all binaries with the tag "example_test" that are located under //path/...

I was wondering if there was a command option to run multiple binaries with a given tag?
 ex) 
`bazel run --run_tag_filter=example_test //path/...` or something alone those lines

Answer (score 0):

Bazel run only supports executing one binary at a time.

However, you have a couple of options if you want to run tests concurrently:

1. Use `bazel test` - I assume you already tried this. You can use [`--test_tag_filters`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_tag_filters) which has the same effect as `--build_tag_filter` has on `bazel build`. You can then control concurrency with `--jobs` and [`--local_test_jobs`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--local_test_jobs).
2. You can also use `bazel run` with [`--script_path`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--script_path) which results in Bazel outputting a shell script which contains all the logic to run the target independently of Bazel. You could, in theory, create a script for each target and then execute them in parallel.